# how can I exclude some words from grep results

Tags: ssh, grep

On `ssh` I am using command 
`ui user | grep UDomain` which gives me result

```
UDomain: test.com
```

How can I exclude   `UDomain:`  and only keep

```
 test.com
```

`grep` sed awk anything will work for me.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Can you give a true output and grep command, along with the expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Command> |grep -oP 'UDomain:.\K.*'
```

Example:

```
ui user |grep -oP 'UDomain:.\K.*'
```

Or use `awk`:

```
command |awk -F: '/UDomain/{print $2}'
```

Or use `sed` :

```
command|sed -r '/UDomain/s/(^.*:)(.*)/\2/g'
```

Comment: perfect ! Thanks !

Comment: I got domain name. now how can I insert that in sed command ?
sed -i '/DB_COLLATE/a \ define('FTP_USER', 'design@$domain’);’ file.php

This command give me error
syntax error near unexpected token `)'

Comment: This is a different problem statement , please ask a new question with clear requirements. Thanks.